# Pinia shared reactivity in stores

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Is it possible to share reactive state between stores in Pinia, for example:

```
export const useMainStore = defineStore('mainStore', {
state: () => ({
    data: [{name: "some name", amount: useSomeStore().amount}]
}),

export const useSomeStore = defineStore('someStore', {
state: () => ({
    amount: 0
}),
```

The idea is that `useSomeStore.amount` value is synced with the `useMainStore` data value.

So when I change the amount in `useSomeStore` to 5 I expect that data value in `useMainStore` will change accordingly to:

```
[{name: "some name", amount: 5}]
```

I know that I can subscribe to the store or use watchers but is there a better solution for this?

I made working solution using storeToRefs but not sure if there are drawbacks to this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-breeze-wylkoj?file=/src/stores/tomato.ts

Comment: Multiple stores are supposed to be combined through getters. Use an action if you need to change mainStore amount without mentioning someStore

Comment: I know this is a possibility, but I'm looking for a way without creating new methods.  Using storeToRefs kinda works, where I take someStore amount and store it as ref in mainStore in amount property, but dunno if it's a good approach.

Comment: If I understand the premise correctly, you don't, actually, want to sync the values (e.g. to store the same value in two places) but you want to access a value in one store from another store. In that case, perhaps, a computed value might be an answer. There's a similar example here: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/getters.html#with-setup

Comment: @Emil I'm not sure what you mean. You can read the value with a getter. If you intend to mutate it without an action, this is a bad practice and significantly cancels the benefits of Pinia. It's not a coincidence that deep mutations are discouraged in Vue in general, e.g. props. it's hard to track them when they don't work as intended

Comment: I made a sandbox with an example https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-breeze-wylkoj?file=/src/App.vue. Basically, I store ref in an array of objects in one of the fields from another store using storeToRefs. That way both values are synchronized, but I don't know if there are drawbacks to this method. There's a simple UI showing store changes, main.ts has the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember pinia states are reactive objects.

Therefore, you can always set a `computed` on one of them which references another store's state.

Generic example:

```js
const useStoreOne = defineStore('one', {
  state: () => ({
    foo: 'bar'
  })
})

const useStoreTwo = defineStore('two', {
  state: () => ({
    foo: computed({
      get() { return useStoreOne().foo },
      set(val) { useStoreOne().foo = val } 
    })
  })
})
```

---

Note: `storeToRefs` does the same as above. So you can write `storeTwo` as:

```js
const useStoreTwo = defineStore('two', {
  state: () => ({
    foo: storeToRefs(useStoreOne()).foo
  })
})
```

---

But it's kind of pointless. Why would you want to use `useStoreTwo().foo` anywhere instead of using `useStoreOne().foo` directly?

Make no mistake: the above pattern sets a two-way binding between the two store's `foo`s. But, the second store's `foo` is useless. Anywhere you use it, you could be using the first one's `foo` directly.

---

On general principles, when you come across this pattern (or across the need for it), it should raise a flag: you're using state management because you want "***one** source of truth*". Not more.

Comment: Okay, now that makes more sense to me, ty very much!